# How to Create a Heatmap based on how frequent (x,y) appears in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns of data, x and y. I want to create a heatmap based on how often the value (x, y) appears in the dataframe.

What I've done so far is

```
g = g.groupby(['x','y'])
g = g.nunique()
```

and that produces

````
g = g.groupby(['x','y'])
g = g.nunique()
```x    y
650 13439.0
670 19000.0
690 33402.0
    250000.0
700 9000.0
... ...

I'm not sure where to go from here, or if I should take a totally new approach to doing this. Thanks for any help.
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe something like `sns.kdeplot(x=g['x'], y=g['y'])`?  Your post could be improved by adding more information.